# Extractor Process PHP getimagesize(): Read error

Tags: php

Im using this code, but still i can handle this error:Extractor Process PHP Notice
  getimagesize(): Read error!

```
 $image = 'https://exampleurl.com';
 if ( @getimagesize($image)) {} 
                else {
                    $image='';
                }
                if(!empty($image)){
                $image1 = 'noImage.jpg';
                $compareMachine = new compareImages($image1);
                $image1Hash = $compareMachine->getHasString(); 
                $image2_url = $image;
                $image2 = 'current_image_url.jpg';
                file_put_contents($image2, $this->get_page($image2_url));
                $image2Hash = $compareMachine->hasStringImage($image2); 
                $diff = $compareMachine->compareHash($image2Hash); 
                echo 'Different rates (orginalImage Vs currentImageUrl): '.$diff;
                if($diff>11){
                    echo ' => 2 different image';
                }
                else{
                    echo ' => duplicate image';
                    $image='';
                }
            }
```

I tried a lot of different things, but my script sometimes stops becuse of this problem, is there any way that my script can continue working and just let me know for this problem?

Comment: Try to download image to local storage (`file_get_contents`) and check file with functions `is_file($filename) && filesize($filename) > 0 && getimagesize($filename)`

Comment: great idea! thanks!